# QGIS polygonize TIFF results in strange vector

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, vector, polygonize

I used an open access data set of GeoTIFFs and used polygonize to transform them into vectors. For the majority of TIFFs this went well, except for two, which create strange longitudinal bars (see images). The TIFF used in the image can be downloaded here (it is the 160_60 TIFF tile/file): https://storage.googleapis.com/uq-intertidal/v1_1/datamask/datamask.zip

Can somebody explain how to solve this problem?

[image]